# PHP: IMAP move email to trash

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to move the email from Inbox to trash box and wrote the following code that always gives error `Error in IMAP command COPY: Invalid messageset (0.000 + 0.000 secs).`

```
$stream = imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to mail: ' . imap_last_error());

if(imap_mail_move($stream, '4', 'INBOX.Trash') or die(imap_last_error())) {
    echo '1';
}
else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

here is the different variations that I tried with

```
imap_mail_move($stream, '4', 'Trash')
imap_mail_move($stream,  4 , 'Trash')
imap_mail_move($stream, '4', 'INBOX/Trash')
imap_mail_move($stream,  4 , 'INBOX/Trash')
```

Comment: Make sure your second param is a valid UID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example it may contain national version of that name. 
Also some Gmail accounts use "[Gmail]/Bin" in English version.
You should use CommonFolders class to recognize folders:

```
$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}';
$connection = imap_open($server, 'user_name@gmail.com', 'password');
$mailboxes = imap_list($connection, $server, '*');
var_dump($mailboxes);
```

In Brazilian Portuguese you can see something like:

```
0 => string '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}INBOX' (length=29)
1 => string '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Com estrela' (length=43)
2 => string '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/E-mails enviados' (length=48)
3 => string '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Importante' (length=42)
4 => string '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Lixeira' (length=39)
5 => string '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Rascunhos' (length=41)
6 => string '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Spam' (length=36)
7 => string '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/Todos os e-mails' (length=48)
```

So, my trash in brazilian portuguese is:
    '[Gmail]/Lixeira'

You need to change your code to your trash.

```
imap_mail_move($stream,  4 , '[Gmail]/Lixeira');
```

Credits:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/open-mailbox-other-than-inbox-php-imap/

Comment: It's noticeable that `imap_mail_move` will just set a move flag. To make the move happen, we need to call `imap_expunge` or `imap_close($imap, CL_EXPUNGE)` where the `CL_EXPUNGE` flag has the same effect as calling  `imap_expunge`.